# Animating a complete change in the toolbar

Tags: ios, core-animation, uitoolbar

I have a toolbar that, at some point in the application, is completely replaced by another toolbar (i.e. another set of toolbar items). How do I animate this replacement?

Note: An ideal animation would be that of sliding the old toolbar items out and sliding the new ones in.

Comment: If you want to have two toolbars on the screen, place the other in line, but at either 768*2 or -768 for an x value.  Then, use a UIView animation to slide one gently off the screen and animate the other's x value to 0.

Comment: I like your idea. Unfortunately my toolbar is being provided by the navigation controller, so I don't know if there's anyway to actually reclaim the toolbar space used by the navigation controller to instantiate a new toolbar. I might just use setToolbarItems:animate: on my view and that should be the end of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best way to do this is to use setToolbarItems:animate: on the active view, thus avoiding the need for another toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this,

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/25045-navigation-controller-custom-animation.html

Comment: Sorry, but this animates the entire window view, not the toolbar.

Comment: For toolbar are you using UITabBarController or not ?

Comment: I am not. I am using the bottom toolbar such as that in UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a `UIToolbar` method that is called `- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated` which does the same as the one mentioned by nessup.